# What can I do when the employer keep delaying my start date with the excuse of applying work permit as I am a foreigner?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, recruitment, hiring-process

I accepted the offer from one of the companies which offer me to work with them. I accepted their offer in the mid of January but the employer kept saying that the work permit is yet to be approved. After talking with them last week, I found out that they totally do not put in the application and they promised me to do it ASAP. I really get frustrated as it was already two months and the longest time it takes to apply the permit is only one month. Now I am applying for new job but I am yet to inform them. How do I politely ask the employer on what is actually going on. To be honest, I actually still hope to work with this company as the compensation and benefits they offer is great.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: A company who forgets an employee and that their ability to work and live in their country for them is hanging on a thread because they forgot to apply for a work visa for said employee for months is hardly one i’d want to work for...

Comment: @morbo, whereas I agree with you, keep into consideration that finding a company to sponsor you abroad is difficult, and for many people, this opportunity could be a once-in-a-lifetime one.

Comment: @Charmander i am a foreigner working in a country not of my own. I know the problems, and you’re right it’s hard. But considering how the company acts now, i cannot recommend that a foreign worker can trust them to be stable in the future either...if you have to leave the country after a year because the company dragged their feet again and missed a deadline, and you have to drop everything and bail...there was hardly a point to go to begin with. Long term stability outweighs great short term opportunities in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

If your potential employer forgets to do arguably the most important piece of paperwork required for you to start doing your job, you keep looking for a new employer.  Until the visa is approved and you have all the completed documentation in hand, you effectively don't have a job.